# Kofax Capture 8 to 10 upgrade

Tags: kofax

We are looking at upgrading from Kofax Capture 8 to 10.

Currently, our Kofax Capture 8 installation on a single server with 3 connected client scanner workstations.

When going to Capture 10 can we use the same single server setup as with the current installation? or install new kofax server in new VM and then copy the batch class and batches into the new server?

What are the things we need considering while upgrading?

Anything that individuals can comment on that would help us (do's -don'ts) would be appreciated?

Thank you.

Comment: I recommend contacting Kofax Support with such questions. If it is an option to install on a fresh VM, I'd recommend this. Test it thoroughly then replace the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're in a virtual environment and with a fairly small number of stations, I suggest you create a snapshot of the server (VMWare and Hyper-V both have this feature) and do an upgrade with the Kofax installer (start installing on KC 10 on the server and the installer will notice that an old version is present and will prompt you for upgrade).
If the upgrade goes wrong then you can revert to the snapshot you created and start over as if nothing happened.
Once the server is OK, upgrade the stations by running the installer from the WrkInst folder on the server. Try on a single station first, and if that works, roll out to the rest.

Answer (score 0):

When going to Capture 10 can we use the same single server setup as with the current installation?--- use can use the same single server.

Things you need to take care of are.

Your configuration path for importing the batches might get change.

Check for the DB connection.

Dictionaries and database path you might need to change again.

check your export connectors mapping they should not be effected in case they are you need to map it again.

Keep a snap shot of things when your installing and have backup taken of project fpr file and batch class so that you can roll back to older changes.

Comment: ftp://ftp.kofax.com/pub/support/capture/kc/10/product_documentation/user_guides/english/KofaxCaptureInstallationGuide.pdf